# Writing check codes and for loops in octave to check max differences of vectors

Tags: for-loop, vector, octave

I have written the following code in octave where cb1-cb27 are vectors and I want to check all possible differences between each of the vectors. Then I want to check what the maximum difference is between them. If the max difference is <= 1 then I want the check to stop and it to tell me. I would like if the difference vectors with max values of 1 could be put into a new matrix. So far what I have isn't quite working and was wondering if anyone has any tips. I have essentially no experience with octave. This is for a personal research project, not a homework assignment.

```
X = [cb1(:), cb2(:), cb3(:), cb4(:), cb5(:), cb6(:), cb7(:), cb8(:), cb9(:), cb10(:),       cb11(:), cb12(:), cb13(:), cb14(:), cb15(:), cb16(:), cb17(:), cb18(:), cb19(:), cb20(:), c.   b21(:), cb22(:), cb23(:), cb24(:), cb25(:), cb26(:), cb27(:)];
    Y = zeros(size(X,1),size(X,2),size(X,2));
        for j = 1:size(X,2)
            for k = 1:size(X,2)
Y(:,j,k) = abs(X(:,j) - X(:,k));
    end
end
```

```
 T=zeros(size(X,2), size(X,2));
    for j= 1:size(X,2)
        for k=1:size(X,2)
            T(j,k)=max(Y(:,j,k));
                if j==k
                    T(j,k)=10;
        end
          end
             end
```

`min(min(T))`

```
check=0;
for j=1:
    for k= 1: 
        if max(Y(:j,k)) <= 1
            check =1;
            check
```

See above code for what I have tried.

Comment: "If the max difference is <= 1 then I want the check to stop" Once you have checked all the differences to figure out what the max difference is, what is there left to stop? Please [edit] your post to clarify what you want to accomplish. Also please clarify what distance measure you want to use for vectors. I would expect Euclidean distance, but the `Y` you build is just an element-wise difference.

Comment: I believe I am trying to do element-wise differences. I am working on coding theory and my vectors are codewords. I want to see if there are any words in my codebook that are within 1 from each other because this means they could be overwritable if an adversary is present.

Comment: So you want to see if any two codewords have no codes that differ by more than one? So you want to compute `max(abs(cb1-cb2))` for each pair, and the first pair you find where this is `<=1` you want to stop comparing because that is the pair you'll work with. You don't care to compare the remainder of the pairs?

Comment: I do want to compare the remainder of the pairs, so maybe I don't want it to stop. I guess I would like it to generate a new matrix with all the differences that are <=1.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the difference matrix `Y` without loops as follows:

```matlab
Y = permute(X, [2,3,1]) - permute(X, [3,2,1]);
```

This has the vectors along the 3rd dimension, which will be convenient later. This does compare vectors against themselves, and also compares each pair twice.

Now we want to compute the maximum absolute difference for each vector pair:

```matlab
T = max(abs(Y), [], 3);
```

Now `T(i,j)` is the maximum absolute difference between vectors `X(:,i)` and `X(:,j)`.

To find which differences are not larger than 1, simply compare: `T<=1`.
We can remove duplicate entries and the diagonal using `tril` or `triu`:

```matlab
T = triu(T <= 1, 1);
```

If you need to have the indices for the vector pairs, use `find` in conjunction with `ind2sub`:

```matlab
[i, j] = ind2sub(size(T), find(T));
```

Now `X(:,i[p])` and `X(:,j[p])` is a pair of vectors that satisfy your constraint on the difference.